# How can i access different parts of this array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using a sites API to check the status of some of my links, it returns the status with json so i'm using `$obj = json_decode($result);` to access it which works fine.

How can i get the status for each of the files, I tried to do `$obj->result->acQeh1UXI-c->status` but i'm guessing that's wrong as it didn't display anything

if i use `print_r($obj);` i get the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 200
    [msg] => OK
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [acQeh1UXI-c] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => acQeh1UXI-c
                    [status] => 200
                    [name] => 2769.rar
                    [size] => 18693570
                    [sha1] => 739c79942bf743b35223fc59e693fcfffc8c8433
                    [content_type] => application/x-rar
                    [cstatus] => 0
                )

            [BNdoJQDSSFo] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => BNdoJQDSSFo
                    [status] => 200
                    [name] => 2589.rar
                    [size] => 99478
                    [sha1] => 56427728d57c0bd611018305a9133eac83ef8a3a
                    [content_type] => application/x-rar
                    [cstatus] => 0
                )

            [OrnGndPlQEI] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => OrnGndPlQEI
                    [status] => 200
                    [name] => 1234.rar
                    [size] => 293646
                    [sha1] => 746e09cfaeef4c9c1e6abb7205e78615e661f21b
                    [content_type] => application/x-rar
                    [cstatus] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: If it is `JSON` you could turn it in to an associative array (`json_decode($val, true);`).

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($obj->result);`?  What about `print_r($obj->result->acQeh1UXI-c);`?  Break your problem into parts.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes i did try to, i already put that in my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you turn in to an associative array by using the second parameter available in `json_decode`.

```
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
```

Then you could,

```
$obj['result']['acQeh1UXI-c']['status'];
```

Comment: @Exoon glad I could help.

Comment: Will do in 4 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried with bracket ?

```
$obj['result']['acQeh1UXI-c']['status']
```

Comment: Yeah i tried that, It doesn't work however i converted it to an associative array as suggested by Script47 and it's working great now. Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Daenu : Actually my feeling was the "-" was causing problem with the "->" access, so I suggested him to use bracket instead because I thought it would fix it. But if it's not a suitable answer I can delete it, no problem.